# Laravel multi tenancy creating first User in tenant database

Tags: database, laravel, multi-tenant

I am following this documentation [Hyn/Multitenant](https://laravel-tenancy.com/docs/hyn/5.3/spatie-laravel-permission) for creating a new user in tenant database from main app but as if i changes the User Model to use TenantConnection it would produce error that tenancy database is not configured. What i would like to ask is if there is any other solution beside creating new Model. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Comment: yup, I found the solution.

Comment: Mind to share your solution?